# Tag merge request for Microsoft Windows Small Business Server tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Here is a list for Microsoft Small Business Server tags that do not mention version number:

- [sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs) x 46
- [sbs-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-server) x 2
- [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) x 96

Here is a list of all SBS tags that I can find which are version specific:

- [sbs-2000](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2000)
- [sbs2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs2003)
- [sbs-2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2003)
- [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008)
- [windows-sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2008)
- [sbs-2011](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2011)

Let's come to an official conclusion about how to name these tags.

#### Generic SBS tag

<strike>I propose [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) be the official base tag for the product line. [sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs) and [sbs-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-server) should be merged into [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server). "Microsoft" and "Windows" don't need to be in the tag. It is better served if that is a separate tag in the question, e.g. [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows) [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) ("Microsoft" is too broad of a keyword and doesn't seem helpful).</strike>

Certainly, the words "small business server" can mean something other than the Microsoft Windows Small Business Server product, but I doubt too many people are going to be tagging a question about a small server for their business with [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) and if they do, it can be retagged. Thoughts?

The new proposal for the generic SBS tag is [windows-sbs-yyyy-feature](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-yyyy-feature) as per [womble's answer below](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1865/tag-merge-request-for-microsoft-windows-small-business-server-tags/1869#1869).

#### Version Specific Tags

<strike>Either we petition for the tag length limit to be increased or we use the acronym "SBS" in the version specific tags. I propose that the nomenclature be SBS-[year]-[additional features]. So [sbs2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs2003) should be merged with [sbs-2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2003). [sbs-2011-essentials](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2011-essentials), while not existing yet, *could* just as [sbs-2011-premium](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2011-premium) may exist as well.</strike>

That means that a post about the Exchange instance running on a Small Business Server 2008 machine would most logically be tagged with [exchange-2007](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchange-2007) and [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008) and possibly include [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) and [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows). Thoughts?

There will be no "base tag" of [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) - all tags will have the acronym "SBS" and the year. Perhaps having "Standard" and "Premium" in the tag isn't pertinent. Although, in SBS 2003 it was very pertinent (it was the difference between is you had ISA Server or not which could significantly change things).

#### Summary

Assuming what I laid out above is accepted, here is the course of action:

1. Merge [sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs), [sbs-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-server) and [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) into [windows-sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs). We'd have to be careful for the questions tagged [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) that don't have anything to do with the Microsoft product.
2. Change [sbs-2000](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2000) into [windows-sbs-2000](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2000)
3. Merge [sbs2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs2003) and [sbs-2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2003) into [windows-sbs-2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2003).
4. Merge [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008) into [windows-sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2008)
5. Change [sbs-2011](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2011) into [windows-sbs-2011](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2011)

EDIT 1:

Okay, as Womble pointed out [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) isn't the best tag for the product. ChrisS points out that [windows-server-yyyy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-yyyy) is the traditional tag format, so the new SBS tag should likely be [windows-sbs-yyyy-feature](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-yyyy-feature). I've updated the action list above to reflect this.

Can tags be "auto-forwarded" so that the [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) is blocked and substituted with [windows-sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs)?

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* disagree that [small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/small-business-server) doesn't need a "microsoft" or "windows" in there; I would say that it's generic enough that someone would likely use it if they were talking about a server for a small business.  A quick scan of the first page of search results for that tag produced several results which certainly don't *look* like they're SBS-related.

That being said, [microsoft-small-business-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-small-business-server) is quite a mouthful (fingerful?); perhaps [microsoft-sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-sbs) or [windows-sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs) would be better (though, admittedly, less discoverable).

Comment: [tag:windows-server-yyyy] is the format for regular server. Makes sense for SBS to be [tag:windows-sbs-yyyy] to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is partially done

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs

not 100% sure that's a good name for this tag.. has anyone tried comparative Google searches to see what actually works in the wild?

- "windows small business server" → About 4,000,000 results (0.16 seconds)
- "windows sbs" → About 1,110,000 results (0.16 seconds)
- "microsoft sbs" → About 299,000 results (0.26 seconds)
- "microsoft small business server" → About 910,000 results (0.23 seconds)

Comment: The first search is pretty long, and adding a year or feature code to a tag like that is going to make it massive, over the character limit. The Second, which is probably the widest recognized by SAs, is the same as Womble's suggestion. Sounds like the way to go.