# Synonym SBS-2008

Tags: discussion, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag merge request for Microsoft Windows Small Business Server tags](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1865/tag-merge-request-for-microsoft-windows-small-business-server-tags)

Looks to be a good synonym candidate. sbs-20xx seems to be the standard with all the other tags as well.

[sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008) x195 <- [windows-sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2008) x6

Answer (score 2):

Should be the other way around [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008) -> [windows-sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2008)